# Expected number of elements greater than randomly chosen element

Tags: probability

Let $S = \{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\} $ be a multiset of real numbers. Let $X$ be a number sampled uniformly from $S$ and let $Y$ represent the number of elements in $S$ that are greater than or equal to $X$.

Then is it possible for us to calculate $E[Y]$ (or some bounds for it) without knowing the specific values in $S$? I suspect that there is some relation between $E[Y]$ and $n/2$ though I can't seem to nail it down exactly. The problem is easy if all the $x_{i}$ are distinct, but if there are duplicates, it seems trickier.

Comment: The difficult issue is "equal to $X$".  So it might be worth changing $S$ into a table of values and their frequencies

Comment: As you say, it is trivial if all the $x_i$ are distinct.  Without more information about how the values of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are chosen, we can not be exact with our answer but we can still say that $E[Y]\geq n/2$

Comment: When all the values are different I think it is $\frac n2+\frac12$.  If you have $n$ multivalues and $d$ discrete values then I suspect it is $n-d+1+\frac{d(d-1)}{2n}$.

Comment: I don't believe this can be definitively answered without more information on how the values of $S$ were chosen, what the multiplicities are, or what the actual values are. However, if the values of $S$ are chosen randomly from the set of real numbers, then I believe the problem is effectively identical to the case were all $x_i$ are distinct because the probability of choosing the same exact real number again approaches $0$.